# Navigation bar(s) disappear when the window gets too small

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

The title maybe is a little misleading but I'm not 100% sure how this effect is called. I'm pretty sure what I meant is that my navigation bar is disappearing instead of **collapsing**.

However my set up is this - I am working on the `Layout` view of `ASP.NET MVC 4` project. I'm using `bootstrap 3x` but also have included `jQuery` libs so my `<head>` part is like this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap.css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.smoothness.css")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js")
//just skipped the standard stuff
```

In the body I want to have two `navbars` and one side menu which will be the same for all my pages but I've noticed that when I start to narrow the window at some point instead of getting an effect similar to [this example](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/fluid.html) (noticed how the elements get repositioned) I just got both my `navbars` gone, I can't see them.

The markup for my first `navbar` is this :

```
<div class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-inverse navbar-collapse collapse" role="navigation">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
            <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and the second one is :

```
<div class="navbar navbar-collapse collapse" role="navigation" id="main-navigation-bar">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
            <li style="border: 1px solid grey"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
```

In fact the only thing left in my `_Layout` body is this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
```

which is just for compiling purposes and renders this view :

```
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
```

So when I make the window small enough so that my navbars disappear the only thing left is `1..5` numbers from the rendered view.

I tested with only one `navbar` (commented the other) - no matter which one is commented, when I narrow the window I loose the navbar. How can I keep them using `bootstrap 3x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start reading [Updating Bootstrap to version 3 - what do I have to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974998/updating-bootstrap-to-version-3-what-do-i-have-to-do/18069643) your example use Twitter's Bootstrap v2 while you use v3.

Some notes:

- v3 don't have a container-fluid class
- there is no support for jQuery v2 (use the latest v1)
- Bootstrap don't suppport multiple navbars on a page, also see: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10229 and [Multiple navbars on the same page with Twitter's Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944282/multiple-navbars-on-the-same-page-with-twitters-bootstrap-3/18944283)
- your second navbar missing a class, see: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10332

Answer (score 1):

The structures of your navbars do not appear to match what is outlined in the [docs for the navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar).

In particular, you are dropping the `.navbar-collapse` and `.collapse` on the main navbar div. I believe this class hides all of the content inside of it when the screen width hits a certain point, so that it can do something similar to what you linked to in the docs.

I am betting that if you restructure your navbars to match what is in the docs, you will eliminate the issues you are seeing.

PS - The class `.container-fluid` doesn't exist anymore. Just use `.container` with Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Well, I tried to escape copy-pasting and just understand what does what but now I just copy-pasted the code from the example on the official site (the one you provided) and it's working. But I really would like to know where my logic breaks, obviously the whole concept about defining buttons for the items I want to toggle but still I struggle for some more detail information, are you able to provide some more in detail source of information about the topic?

Comment: Do you want detail on why your code wasn't working, or why the navbar is structured like it is?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I read a lot tonight I I got the basic idea behind the navigation bar in bootstrap. Still a lot of thing are not clear, but I will open a new questions for the different problems. This one is solved.